# multiple checkbox validation javascript

Tags: javascript

I know there are many threads online and I have tried them all but it is still not working, Please help.
I want to make sure that at least one program is selected. I checked console but there are no errors, also it says debugger not activated.

JavaScript:

```
function validateForm() {
        if (document.getElementById('cfname').value === '') {
        document.getElementById('errcfname').innerHTML = "Please enter firstname";
        return false;
        }

        if (document.enrollment.clname.value == "") {
        document.getElementById('errclname').innerHTML = "Please enter lastname";
        clname.focus();
        return false;
        }

        if(validateRadio (document.getElementsByName('gender'))) {
            return true;
        } else {
            document.getElementById('errgender').innerHTML = "Please specify gender";
            return false;
        }

        var chk = document.getElementsByName('program[]');
        var len = chk.length;
            var checked = false;
        for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
             if(chk[i].checked) {
                checked=true;
                            break;
                      }
            }
        if (!checked) {
                document.getElementById('errpgm').innerHTML = "Please specify program"; 
                return false;
              } 
        }
        return true;
    }
    function validateRadio(radios) {
        for (i = 0; i < radios.length; ++ i) {
            if (radios[i].checked) 
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    function validate(id,error) {
        var value = document.getElementById(id).value;
        var err = document.getElementById(error);
        if(!value) {
            err.innerHTML = "*required";
        } else {
            err.innerHTML = "*";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Check console and post error.

Comment: As already pointed out in your previous question - http://www.webmonkey.com/2010/02/javascript_debugging_for_beginners/

Comment: I was using firebug, but now it says debugger not activated.

Comment: @RiteshA there are no errors.

Comment: @Pekka웃 thank you so much, I found the error by debugging.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is here:

```
> var chk = document.getElementsByName('program[]');
> var len = chk.length;
> 
> for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
>
>   if (chk[i].checked) {
>     return true;
>  
>   } else {
>     document.getElementById('errpgm').innerHTML = "Please specify gender";  
>     return false;
>   }
> }
```

In the above, only the first checkbox will be tested, then the function will return true or false based on whether it was checked or not. If you want the user to select only one checkbox, use radio buttons instead and have one checked by default. Otherwise, use something like:

```
var oneChecked = false;
while (i-- && !oneChecked) {
  oneChecked = chk[i].checked;
}

if (!oneChecked) {
  document.getElementById('errpgm').innerHTML = "Please specify gender";  
  return false;
}
```

Also, the error message doesn't seem appropriate for the checkbox values, as they don't seem to have anything to do with gender.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    var chk = document.getElementsByName('program[]');
    var len = chk.length;
    var has_program = false;
    for(i=0;i<len;i++) {
         if(chk[i].checked) {
            has_program = true;
            break;    
          } 
    }
    if( !has_program )
    {
         document.getElementById('errpgm').innerHTML = "Please specify gender";
         return false;
    }

    return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you've overcomplicated things.

For starters, you should be using a client-side framework like jQuery. I have provided a JSFiddle with how this could work for you here, http://jsfiddle.net/nickyt/g2Ab3.

If you were to do this in plain JavaScript, You would  use something like this:

`document.forms[0]["program[]"]`

to get all the checkboxes in the checkbox group. From there you would loop this collection and if none of the form elements have the `.checked` property, you would fail the validation, but as I mention, jQuery handles a lot of this basic JavaScript for you. I think readining up on jQuery selectors would also benefit you, http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors